# Ignore pod anti affinity during deployment update

Tags: kubernetes

Imagine in a Master-Node-Node setup where you deploy a service with pod anti-affinity on the Nodes: An update of the Deployment will cause another pod being created but the scheduler not being able to schedule, because both Nodes have the anti-affinity.

**Q:** How could one more flexibly set the anti-affinity to allow the update?

```
affinity:
   podAntiAffinity:
     requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
     - labelSelector:
         matchExpressions:
         - key: app
           operator: In
           values:
           - api
     topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

With an error

```
No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: MatchInterPodAffinity (2), PodToleratesNodeTaints (1).
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace the 'hard' to 'soft' affinity? I mean, replace the 'requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution' to 'preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution'?

Answer (score 11):

Look at [Max Surge](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-surge)

If you set Max Surge = 0, you are telling Kubernetes that you won't allow it to create more pods than the number of replicas you have setup for the deployment. This basically  forces Kubernetes to remove a pod before starting a new one, and thereby making room for the new pod first, getting you around the podAntiAffinity issue. I've utilized this mechanism myself, with great success.

**Config example**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
    ...
spec:
  replicas: <any number larger than 1>
    ...
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 0
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
    ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - api
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

**Warning:** Don't do this if you only have one replica, as it will cause downtime because the only pod will be removed before a new one is added. If you have a huge number of replicas, which will make deployments slow because Kubernetes can only upgrade 1 pod at at a time, you can crank up *maxUnavailable* to enable Kubernetes to remove a higher number of pods at a time.

Comment: great answer, it made my day!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few methods which may work:

1. Modify your deployment rollingUpdate strategy 'Max Unavailable' parameter be at least 1, which allows for one pod of the old deployment to be destroyed immediately, making room for one pod of the new deployment to be created.

[Max Unavailable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable)

> .spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable is an optional field that specifies the maximum number of Pods that can be unavailable during the update process. The value can be an absolute number (for example, 5) or a percentage of desired Pods (for example, 10%). The absolute number is calculated from percentage by rounding down. The value cannot be 0 if .spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge is 0. The default value is 25%.
>
> For example, when this value is set to 30%, the old ReplicaSet can be scaled down to 70% of desired Pods immediately when the rolling update starts. Once new Pods are ready, old ReplicaSet can be scaled down further, followed by scaling up the new ReplicaSet, ensuring that the total number of Pods available at all times during the update is at least 70% of the desired Pods.
> Max Surge

2. Modify the deployment pod spec to use "soft" anti-affinity instead of "hard".

[Pod Anti-Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity-beta-feature)

> There are currently two types of node affinity, called requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution and preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution. You can think of them as “hard” and “soft” respectively, in the sense that the former specifies rules that must be met for a pod to be scheduled onto a node (just like nodeSelector but using a more expressive syntax), while the latter specifies preferences that the scheduler will try to enforce but will not guarantee.

Comment: Soft anti-affinity will make load to be distributed not evenly during the rolling update.